# Different validators based on input

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am in the design phase of a project which needs to perform certain validations on a given object.
The validations can be grouped into 5 distinct groups. Each individual category of validator can have multiple versions differing slightly in their implementations.

```
public interface Validator {
 boolean validate(Object o);
}

public abstract CostValidator implements Validator {
 //common logic related to cost validator
}

public class CostValidator1 extends CostValidator {
 boolean validate(Object o) {
   //implementation 1
 }

public class CostValidator2 extends CostValidator {
 boolean validator(Object o) {
  //implementation 2
 }
```

Based on the business group of the object, either CostValidator1 or CostValidator2 needs to be executed.

For each business group, I plan on maintaining a list of such validators in a configuration system i.e:

```
BusinessGroupA {
validators = [CostValidator1, SomeOtherValidator2...]
}

BusinessGroupB {
validators = [CostValidator2, AnotherValidator99...]
}
```

[image]

The processing flow will fetch the list of validators from the configuration based on the business group and execute the validations in each of the validators thus contained.

Are there any flaws with this approach?
Or is there any better way to address the use-case I described?

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a better way of designing this given the requirements.
Since my project is in the design phase, I want to explore as many alternatives as I can.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why validation logic is put into separate class(es)? Why objects cannot validate themselves? `if (!object1.isValid()) {...}`

Comment: Based on the business group an object belongs to, CostValidator1 or CostValidator2 or no Cost validation is applied.

Similarly, objects belonging to Group A may have 3 validators in the pipeline where as those belong to B have 5.

Also, an object may be moved from one business group to another as per changes needed in the future.

This object will be acted upon by various components, implementing their own aspect of business logic. 
The validators listed here belong to one such logical grouping.

Also, the code base for object's class follows a more functional approach vs OO

Comment: In the UML diagram - all of the arrows are pointing in the wrong direction.  A class should point to the interface it implements or the class it extends.

Comment: You're right. I just drew a quick throw-away diagram for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to add two improvements to the above solution:

**1. Guarantee the presence of required validation rules**

Assuming that for each business group relevant validations should be executed, there should be some mechanism to guarantee that the configuration specifies enough validation rules, i.e. validation classes. If you have tens of properties and maybe hundreds of business groups, it would be too easy to make an error in the configuration, i.e. not specify any validator for Cost. My suggestion would be to specify on the level of business object which properties need to have a validator. Then create some kind of object factory that will bind validators to the object based on business group and validation requirement.

I would follow this approach:

1. Create an interface for each type of validation, e.g. ICostValidator and IWeightValidator.
2. In your configuration keep a list of validator interfaces that are required for the business object, e.g.:

   requiredValidators = [ICostValidator, IWeightValidator];
3. When executing the validation on BusinessGroupA or BusinessGroupB, always check if the configured validators implement all of the requiredInterfaces.

**2. Decouple the validators from the specific business object**

If you look at cost and weight validation now they are bound to the business object. I do not know the rest of your class diagram, but I could imagine that the properties for cost and weight would appear in multiple business objects, like for example Item, QuotationLine, SalesOrderLine, ShippingLine etc. Then it would be good to have validators that do not directly depend on the business object and can be easily applied to multiple business objects. In the object factory you could also take care of the proper binding between validators and underlying objects.

Let me know if you would like some code examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
1. That's a very valid point and I was also thinking of putting in place some mechanism to ensure that some validators are not missed accidentally. I'll factor this into my design.
2. You're right. Although, I don't see a use-case for these validators acting on multiple business objects today, but one can never be sure with what changes may be needed in the future.
Would it be possible to provide some more details on achieving the first point you mentioned in the answer?